# Global variables shared across all requests in Pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid, pylons

I have this code in Pylons that calculates the network usage of the Linux system on which the webapp runs. Basically, to calculate the network utilization, we need to read the file `/proc/net/dev` twice, which gives us the the amount of transmitted data, and divide the subtracted values by the time elapsed between two reads.

I don’t want to do this calculation at regular intervals. There’s a JS code which periodically fetches this data. The transfer rate is the average amount of transmitted bytes between two requests per time unit. In Pylons, I used `pylons.app_globals` to store the reading which is going to be subtracted from the next reading at subsequent request. But apparently there’s no `app_globals` in Pyramid and I’m not sure if using thread locals is the correct course of action. Also, although request.registry.settings is apparently shared across all requests, I’m reluctant to store my data there, as the name implies it should only store the settings.

```
def netUsage():
    netusage = {'rx':0, 'tx':0, 'time': time.time()}
    rtn = {}
    net_file = open('/proc/net/dev')
    for line in net_file.readlines()[2:]:
        tmp = map(string.atof, re.compile('\d+').findall(line[line.find(':'):]))
        if line[:line.find(':')].strip() == "lo":
            continue
        netusage['rx'] += tmp[0]
        netusage['tx'] += tmp[8]
    net_file.close()
    rx = netusage['rx'] - app_globals.prevNetusage['rx'] if app_globals.prevNetusage['rx'] else 0
    tx = netusage['tx'] - app_globals.prevNetusage['tx'] if app_globals.prevNetusage'tx'] else 0
    elapsed = netusage['time'] - app_globals.prevNetusage['time']
    rtn['rx'] = humanReadable(rx / elapsed)
    rtn['tx'] = humanReadable(tx / elapsed)

    app_globals.prevNetusage = netusage
    return rtn

@memorize(duration = 3)
def getSysStat():
    memTotal, memUsed = getMemUsage()
    net = netUsage()
    loadavg = getLoadAverage()
    return {'cpu': getCPUUsage(),
            'mem': int((memUsed / memTotal) * 100),
            'load1': loadavg[0],
            'load5': loadavg[1],
            'load15': loadavg[2],
            'procNum': loadavg[3],
            'lastProc': loadavg[4],
            'rx': net['rx'],
            'tx': net['tx']
            }
```

Comment: This question also depends on the type of the web server used. The problem is that you might not know how many processes or threads your web servers spawn for Python. Thus, if you have two or more processes, they cannot no longer share globals.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa, I know, but it's not like I'm storing the DB connection pool there. I don't think thread safety is an issue for my use case, is it?

Comment: I guess then normal Python globals work for you. Just put your function to some module and import there. Unless your Python process is restarted, memorize should work between the requests.

Answer (score 2):

Using request thread locals is considered bad design and should not be abused according to official [pyramid docs](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/threadlocals.html).

My advice is to use some simple key-value storage like [memcached](http://memcached.org/) or [redis](http://redis.io/) if possible.

Comment: Hmm. Seem like overkill. I'm more in favour of an in-house solution.